# Distribution Certificate not shown as an option when Generating a Provisioning Profile

Tags: ios, testflight, apple-developer, apple-developer-account

**Background:** trying to set up `test-flight` for IOS development as an individual.

**Problem:** 
In the Apple developer website, 
while I can see my `distribution certificate` and my `developer certificate` under the `Certificates` tab, when I try to generate a Provisioning Profile, it only shows the `developer certificate` as an option but not the `distribution certificate` (which to my understanding is what is needed to set up test-flight).

perhaps Apple is just taking a while to process the new `distribution certificate` as I created it just now...? 
any ideas? what might have I missed?

Maybe I am supposed to delete the `development certificate` first?

Comment: Have you actually tried archiving and uploading to TestFlight? If you're using automatic signing, Xcode should just generate the distribution identity and certificate when you start the upload (exporting from the archive).

Comment: Your question is not very clear what are you trying to achieve. Also TestFlight setup is in the App Store Connect not in the Apple Developer. Are you trying to setup yourself as a tester? Or are you trying to setup someone else as a tester? Or Are you trying to upload a build of your app for testing? Be more specific when saying trying to setup TestFlight